# How to preserve bookmarks when rearranging pages of a PDF file with tools like pdftk?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I am using `pdftk` to rearrange pages of a pdf file with bookmarks/outlines, but after that, the output file lost the bookmarks of the original.

My command is `pdftk in.pdf cat 1-22 43 23-42 44-end output out.pdf`.

I was wondering how I could keep the bookmarks while rearranging pages?

Answer (score 18):

Here is a working solution. However you will need to adjust it to fit your needs.

In my example i removed the first page of a PDF, and then i needed to update the bookmarks to point to the correct locations.

1. remove page 1 from in.pdf:

   ```
   pdftk A=in.pdf cat A2-end output temp.pdf
   ```
2. create a in.info file from in.pdf:

   ```
   pdftk in.pdf dump_data > in.info
   ```
3. in.info needs to be corrected in my case, since i will remove a page.

   Thus, i need to decrease BookmarkPageNumber by one for the bookmarks to
   lead to the correct pages.

   php code:

   ```
   $file = "in.info";
   $data = file_get_contents($file);

   foreach (explode("\n", $data) as $row) {
       $tmp = explode(": ", $row);

       if ($tmp[0] == "BookmarkPageNumber") {
           if ($tmp[1] != "1") $tmp[1]--;
           echo $tmp[0].": ".$tmp[1]."\n";
       } else {
           echo $row."\n";
       }
   }
   ```
4. create final out.pdf:

   ```
   pdftk temp.pdf update_info in2.info output out.pdf
   ```

tested working on debian using pdftk 2.01

Comment: Worked for me too. Maybe you could add a hint on how to execute your script (no idea how...) or add a python script: `#!/usr/bin/python
output = open('res.info','w')
with  open('temp.info','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("BookmarkPageNumber"):
            output.write( "BookmarkPageNumber: "+ str(int(line.split()[1])+1)+"\n")
        else:
            output.write(line)`

Comment: I use `dump_data_utf8` and `update_info_utf8` because bookmarks might contain special characters.

Comment: The data dump `in.info` also contains `NumberOfPages: X` that may need updating, depending on each case

Answer (score 7):

Reading the [man page](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page) with care, it says that `update_info` takes data in whatever format `dump_data` generates. That presumably would have to be adjusted according to the page shuffling. Doesn't sound *impossible*, but automatic it isn't.

The [PDFtk site](http://www.pdflabs.com) only gives the above hit and creating/editing bookmarks as results. All Google knows about the matter of bookmarks in PDF and reorganizing, is hits on the above operations and lyrical expositions on the marvels they offer, and this thread ;-).

So it seems it can't be done. The comments suggest some possibilities, which didn't work when tried.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do `pdftk in.pdf dump_data > in.info`, then add the `update_info` parameter when generating the `out.pdf`.  Quoting from `man pdftk`:

> ```
> update_info <info data filename | - | PROMPT>
> ```
>
> Changes the metadata stored in a single PDF's Info dictionary to match the input data file. The input data file uses the same syntax as the out‐
>                    put from dump_data. Non-ASCII characters should be encoded as XML numerical entities. This does not change the metadata stored in the PDF's XMP
>                    stream, if it has one. For example:

```
             pdftk in.pdf update_info in.info output out.pdf

  update_info_utf8 <info data filename | - | PROMPT>
```

> Same as update_info except that the input is encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks! How shall I get this file "in.info"?

Comment: @Tim: edited. I hope it's clear now. You need to use `dump_data_utf8` for `update_info_utf8` to work, of course.

Comment: Thanks! It still doesn't work. My commands are in three steps: `pdftk in.pdf dump_data > in.info`, `pdftk in.pdf cat 1-22 43 23-42 44-end output out.pdf` and `pdftk out.pdf update_info in.info output out1.pdf` There are still no bookmarks in `out1.pdf`.
`

Comment: @Tim I can confirm that this does indeed not work. Have you found any solution to this by any chance?

Comment: @MHC: Not yet...

Comment: My cursory Google trawling suggests that bookmarks aren't handled at all.

Comment: @vonbrand It would be too bad, if that's the case. If noone else finds a solution in the next days would you be so kind to write up an answer and include your sources on bookmark handling? That way the bounty wouldn't go to waste and future readers will have something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

"pdfmod" is a simple graphical tool which allows to remove one or mode pages from an existing PDF. It is just matter of a few clicks. It also preserves the content information and cross-linking in the pdf.

"pdftk" works good and I was using it for a long time but I used to lose content after removing one or two pages from the pdf. Those pdf files which are tested in "pdftk" and "pdfmod" are created from openoffice.

https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/pdfmod

Comment: `pdfmod` seems better than `pdftk` when it comes to preserving metadata. A diff of `exiftool` output shows that `pdfmod` preserves the metadata, but `pdftk` does not preserve everything, even if you use `dump_data_utf8` & `update_info_utf8`.

Answer (score 1):

qpdf works like a charm at least under cygwin.
it preserves the links as long as you do not use the `--empty` option :

```
qpdf input.pdf --pages input.pdf 1,4,5,7-r8,2,3,r7-z -- output.qpdf.pdf
```

(rN is to select a page indexed from end, z the last page)

Comment: Works for me as well under Arch Linux with qpdf Version 11.5.0. However, while this will update the page number of the bookmarks, it will not reorder the bookmarks, which may be annoying if you e.g. move a chapter to the end of book. So I still had to edit the bookmarks with pdftk (but this is still easier than changing every page number).